# GREP or AWK: Search in the first N characters of each line, and output surrounding lines that match pattern

Tags: linux, awk, grep, pattern-matching, sequencing

I have a RNA-seq data that looks like this:

```
@J00157:85:HNNJLBBXX:5:1101:2869:15047 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+TATAGCCT
CGACGCTCTTCCGATCTGAGCTGCAGCCTCGGCCCCAGGATCCCCCTGGGGGACTGGACGCTGCTATTGATTCACGAGGCGCTCAGATCGGAAGAGCACAC
+
AAFFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJFJJJFJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
--
@J00157:85:HNNJLBBXX:5:1101:12550:15574 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+TATAGCCT
GCTCTTCCGATCTGCTATTGATGACTGTCCTCTGTTCTTTCTTTCACAGTAGACGAGGACAGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACATTACTC
+
AAAFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
--
```

If we treat all content after @ as a section, you can see only the second line is the real sequencing information, 1,3,4,5 are logistic/quality information.

The **goal** is **to extract sequences (second line information) that containing "GCTGCA" in the first N (N=35) characters each line**, and **at the same time output the surrounding lines (1 line ahead, 3 line behind the matched line)**.

An example answer is

```
@J00157:85:HNNJLBBXX:5:1101:2869:15047 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+TATAGCCT
CGACGCTCTTCCGATCTGAGCTGCAGCCTCGGCCCCAGGATCCCCCTGGGGGACTGGACGCTGCTATTGATTCACGAGGCGCTCAGATCGGAAGAGCACAC
+
AAFFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJFJJJFJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
--
```

What I have tried are

```
awk 'substr($0, 1, 35) ~ "GCTGCA"' filename.fastq > newfile.fastq
grep -B 1 -A 2 -E GCTGCA filename.fastq > newfile.fastq
awk '{a[++i]=$0;}{substr(a[++i], 1, 35) ~ "GCTGCA"}{for(j=NR-1;j<=NR+2;j++)print a[j];}' filename.fastq > newfile.fastq
```

The first one cannot output surrounding lines.  The second one cannot limit pattern-matching in the first 35 letters of each line.  The third line should work, but it gives me wired output (which obviously is not correct):

```
@J00157:85:HNNJLBBXX:5:1101:14235:1367 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+TATAGCCT
@J00157:85:HNNJLBBXX:5:1101:14235:1367 1:N:0:ATTACTCG+TATAGCCT
TCTNCTCTTCCGATCTACCCCACACACCCCCGCCGCCGCCGCCGCCGCCGCCCTCCGACGCACACCACACGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCCGCCCCCGCCGCTCC
TCTNCTCTTCCGATCTACCCCACACACCCCCGCCGCCGCCGCCGCCGCCGCCCTCCGACGCACACCACACGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCCGCCCCCGCCGCTCC
+
+
AAF#FJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJAJJJJJFJJJJ7JJ
AAF#FJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJAJJJJJFJJJJ7JJ
--
--
```

Comment: Your formatting gets a little ugly at the end. Can you fix it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

with `gawk` multi-char RS support.

```
awk -v RS='\n--' -F'\n' 'substr($2,0,35)~"GCTGCA"{print $0 RS}' file
```

you define the record with the record separator.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` using `getline`:

*search.awk*:

```
substr($0,0,35)~"GCTGCA"  {
    print p # Print the previous line ...
    print # ... , current line ...
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++) { # ... and the 3 lines following it
        getline
        print
    }
}

# Store the previous line
{ p = $0 }
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -f search.awk input_file
```

---

Or without regular expressions and with a parameter:

*search.awk*

```
index(substr($0,0,35), search)  {
    print l
    print
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++) {
        getline
        print
    }
}

{ l = $0 }
```

Call it like

```
awk -v search="GCTGCA" -f search.awk input_file
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  But I do not know how to build this search.awk.  I copy and paste your code section to linux, it gives me error here: { buffer() }
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
Did I do this in the right way?

Comment: put it into a file called `search.awk`